# Visual Studio, GLUT error - The following is a new check for GLUT 3.0; update your code. redisplay needed for window 1, but no display callback

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, graphics, glut, opengl-3

The code is building successfully but when I run the code I have the following error -
The following is a new check for GLUT 3.0; update your code.
GLUT: Fatal Error in D:\6th Sem\4. CG UCS505\EasyAlgo\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe: redisplay needed for window 1, but no display callback.

I've tried everything but am not able to figure it out, am new with open gl and vs. Thank you for your help.

Here is the .cpp file code - 
[source.cpp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wqcdwV59mHVLNy4F88coiQap6nbXxNxb/view?usp=sharing)

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <debug.hpp>
#include <config.hpp>
#include <blobs.hpp>
#include <fonts.hpp>
#include <draw.hpp>
#include <highlight.hpp>
#include <animation.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned short mainWindow, subWindow1, subWindow2;

void Init(float, float, float);
void Init(float, float, float, int, int);
void mainInit();
void display();
void onClick(int, int, int, int);
void keyPress(unsigned char, int, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    mode = "InsertionSort";
    b1.bv.resize(7, blobs());
    int rad[7] = { 28,32,20,28,36,45,31 };
    for (int p = 0; p < 7; p++)
        b1.bv[p].radius = (float)rad[p];
    b1.min = 20;
    b1.max = 45;
#endif

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    std::string title = "AlgoLucidator " + AL_VERSION;
    mainWindow = glutCreateWindow(title.c_str());
    glutPositionWindow(WIN_POS_X, WIN_POS_Y);
    mainInit();
    glutMouseFunc(onClick);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPress);

    subWindow1 = glutCreateSubWindow(mainWindow, 0, 0, WindowWidth / 4, WindowHeight);
    Init(0.80f, 0.80f, 0.60f);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPress);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    subWindow2 = glutCreateSubWindow(mainWindow, WindowWidth / 4, 0, 3 * WindowWidth / 4, WindowHeight);
    Init(0.65f, 0.75f, 0.70f);
    std::string mainInstruct = "Press 1. InsertionSort   2. BubbleSort   3. Dijkstra";
    printText(0, 0, 0, -(5 * mainInstruct.size()), 540, mainInstruct);
    glutMouseFunc(onClick);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPress);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void Init(float r, float g, float b)
{
    int CurrWindowWidth = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    int CurrWindowHeight = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glClearColor(r, g, b, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(-CurrWindowWidth, CurrWindowWidth, -CurrWindowHeight, CurrWindowHeight);
    drawTitle(CurrWindowWidth, CurrWindowHeight);
}

void Init(float r, float g, float b, int width, int height)
{
    glClearColor(r, g, b, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(-width, width, -height, height);
    drawTitle(width, height);
}

void mainInit()
{
    int CurrWindowWidth = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    int CurrWindowHeight = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0, CurrWindowWidth, 0, CurrWindowHeight);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.80f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void display()
{
    glFlush();
}

void onClick(int button, int state, int oldx, int oldy)
{}

void keyPress(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    int activeWindow = glutGetWindow();
    switch (key)
    {
    case 13:  if (b1.pushreq)
    {
        b1.bv.push_back(blobs((float)base_radius));
    }
           if (activeWindow != subWindow2)
               glutSetWindow(subWindow2);
           if (mode == "InsertionSort")
           {
               drawInsertionSort();
           }
           else if (mode == "BubbleSort")
           {
               drawBubbleSort();
           }
           break;

    case 27:  glutDestroyWindow(mainWindow);  //Esc
        break;

    case 49:  mode = "InsertionSort";
        b1.reset();
        glutSetWindow(subWindow2);
        glutMouseFunc(onClick2);
        Init2(0.65f, 0.75f, 0.70f);
        drawTitle3(960, 640);
        break;

    case 50:  mode = "BubbleSort";
        glutSetWindow(subWindow2);
        glutMouseFunc(onClick3);
        glutIdleFunc(display);
        Init3(0.65f, 0.75f, 0.70f);
        drawTitle4(960, 640);
        break;

    default:;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must past the relevant code in the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried doing that but half the code was coming as pain text

Comment: [StackOverflow Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty much exactly telling what's wrong and how to fix it (QFT):

> The following is a new check for GLUT 3.0; update your code. GLUT: Fatal Error in `(…) Project1.exe`: redisplay needed for window 1, but no display callback.

For first window you create, window one, the one created with `glutCreateWindow` you don't specify a display callback:

```
mainWindow = glutCreateWindow(title.c_str());
glutPositionWindow(WIN_POS_X, WIN_POS_Y);
mainInit();
glutMouseFunc(onClick);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyPress);
/// <<<<<<<< something is missing here    
subWindow1 = glutCreateSubWindow(mainWindow, 0, 0, WindowWidth / 4, WindowHeight);
```

Give that first window you create a display callback and the error will go away.

On a second note: Nothing of what's happening in the `…Init` functions is initialization at all. OpenGL is a state machine, and everything done in `…Init` is state prepration that ought to happen at the start of rendering a frame.

Comment: Yeah got it! I had to to add   glutDisplayFunc(display); where you wrote 'something is missing here'. Thank you!